# RecyclerViews listItem x,y coordinates android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to get x and y coordinates of RecyclerView listItem . I have tried below methods but all are returning zero .Any help is appreciated

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int x,y;
    int arr[] =new int[2];
    holder.imageView.getLocationOnScreen(arr);



    Log.d(TAG,"x axis:"+arr[0]+",arr[1]:"+arr[1]);
    float d = holder.imageView.getWidth();
    Log.d(TAG,"Diameter 3:"+holder.itemView.getHeight());
    Log.d(TAG,"Right:"+holder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth());


}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?